# RDS Proxy: Database menu is empty, can't create proxy

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-rds, amazon-rds-proxy

I need my lambda to connect to an Aurora Serverless cluster, through an RDS Proxy. But I can't create the proxy because the *Database* dropdown menu - in the section under *Target group configuration* - is empty.

I have several databases. I have access to the databases. They simply don't appear. The form is unusable.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem ended up being that RDS proxy doesn't work with Aurora Serverless databases. This is stated directly in the docs, but I missed it:

> You can't use RDS Proxy with Aurora Serverless clusters.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/rds-proxy.html#rds-proxy.limitations

Answer (score 7):

I faced the same problem for a different reason:
**The following RDS Proxy prerequisites and limitations apply to PostgreSQL:
For RDS PostgreSQL, RDS Proxy supports version 10.10 and higher minor versions, and version 11.5 and higher minor versions.** And my db was 12.5

There are a few other things why you could not use RDS proxy:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/rds-proxy.html

Comment: this link saved my sanity. I've been stuck on this for two weeks. God bless you Bence Vass